# Disable ibus daemon when start

Tags: kubuntu, ibus

I want to diable ibus daemon when starts and I don't want use it.I use latest kubuntu version.How can I do it?

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/719792/515980) worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE has an **Autostart** tab in the **System Settings**. Open it and disable any programs you don't want starting on Desktop launch.

Comment: The problem is that ibus does not appear in Autostart or in Background-services.